# React Google map . Fix the marker in the center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api, react

I want the functionality as Uber/ola app where the marker is fixed in the center evenwhen we drag the map the marker should be fixed in the center. And finally when the drag end we need to get the lcoation of the marker. I am using react js (google-map-react library)

```
{

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import { geolocated } from "react-geolocated";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

Geocode.setApiKey("key");

class GoogleMap extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: {},
    selectedPlace: "",
    markerCoordinate: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  };
  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
    this.setState({
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  };

  onMapClicked = props => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  };

  onMapReady = () => {
    this.setState({
      markerCoordinate: {
        lat: this.props.coords.latitude,
        lng: this.props.coords.longitude
      }
    });

    this.getAddressfromCoordinates(
      this.state.markerCoordinate.lat,
      this.state.markerCoordinate.lng
    );
  };

  onMarkerDragEnd = coord => {
    const { latLng } = coord;
    const lat = latLng.lat();
    const lng = latLng.lng();
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      markerCoordinate: {
        lat: this.props.coords.latitude,
        lng: this.props.coords.longitude
      }
    });
    this.getAddressfromCoordinates(lat, lng);
  };

  getAddressfromCoordinates = (lat, lng) => {
    Geocode.fromLatLng(lat, lng).then(
      response => {
        const address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
        this.setState({ selectedPlace: address });
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  };
  change = (center) => {
    console.log(center);
  };
  render() {
    let body = <h1>loading...</h1>;

    if (this.props.coords) {
      body = (
        <Map
          style={{
            height: "50%",
            width: "50%",
            margin: "0px auto"
          }}
          ref="map"
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={14}
          onReady={this.onMapReady}
          initialCenter={{
            lat: this.props.coords.latitude,
            lng: this.props.coords.longitude
          }}
          onMouseover={(t,map,e)=>this.change(e)}
          onClick={this.onMapClicked}
        >
          <Marker
            draggable
            animation={this.props.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
            onDragend={(t, map, coord) => this.onMarkerDragEnd(coord)}
            onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          ></Marker>
          <InfoWindow
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
            onClose={this.onMapClicked}
          >
            <div>
              <h1 style={{ fontSize: "10px" }}>{this.state.selectedPlace}</h1>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">{body}</header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "key"
})(
  geolocated({
    positionOptions: {
      enableHighAccuracy: false
    },
    userDecisionTimeout: 5000
  })(GoogleMap)
);
}
```